# !Git clean running 100% CPU

Tags: git

I'm having a really strange yet annoying issue with git, for some reason it's running 100% CPU usage on one of the cores for no reason. When viewed in `htop` its trying to run `git clean -nd .` and I've no idea why it's even doing this all of a sudden, on top of that I can't kill it from `htop` I tried with `SIGKILL` `SIGQUIT` and even `SIGSTOP`, but none seems to be able to kill it because it starts itself back up again.

Git is running as my user account name, and not even root can kill it either. I've also tried reinstalling but that didn't work either. Why would git be running `git clean -nd .` anyway when it's not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the current stable version of git, update if needed. If it is already the right version, report the bug (assuming one is not known already).

Comment: I'm currently using `git version 1.8.3.2` which hasn't been giving me the problem before til now. :o

Comment: @user94959 It looks like they've been on version 2 for a while... Even though the problem just started, it could still be a bug which has long been fixed. So again, I would start with an upgrade, and if that doesn't solve the problem, consider it a bug. If git is the only process doing this, then the problem is most likely with git.