# Why is `git clean` always running?

Tags: git, cleanup

#### Summary:

I noticed that my system was always busy doing something, even when it should be idle. It turns out that `git` is always running -- specifically, in the System Monitor I can see `git clean -nd /home/torben`. This process is using 12% of my CPU which is an 8-core i7 = that's a lot of processing.

I don't know why this is always running, and if I kill it, it starts again automatically. If I don't kill but only *stop* it, the CPU load drops to zero.

**--> What is going on with `git` on my machine? How can I fix this?**

---

**Details:**
Here's how to read the CPU history chart below:

- The `git clean` process is paused ("stopped") at this time.
- From 600 to ~400 seconds: normal idle with Google Chrome in foreground.
- Around ~400 seconds, I used the computer for a moment then minimized Chrome.
- Then until ~240 seconds, the system was truly idle. This is what I expect. (I don't understand why an idle browser uses significant CPU but not when minimized - but that's not my point in this post.)
- Around 240 seconds ago, I gave the stopped `git` process the `continue` command in System Monitor. Chrome is still minimized and I am not using the computer, just observing. **`git` is jumping between 4 different CPU's, using 100% of each for a while before jumping to the next one.**
- At around 40 seconds ago, the system is becoming more busy again because I launched Gimp and started taking screenshots.
- Evidently the system isn't also doing anything else at the same time (music, torrents, etc.).

Based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533416/git-clean-running-100-cpu)'s answer, I have checked that my `git` version is okay at "2.1.0".
`apt-get install git` yields `git is already the newest version`.
Seeing as how it has existed in much older versions, I doubt that this is still a bug in `git` itself?
Is my system defective in some way, or is this really a long-known bug that is not yet fixed?

Note that I'm not a big programmer that uses `git` a lot. I only added it because I wanted to make a [shell script](https://github.com/torbengb/bash/blob/master/daylight-wallpaper-install.sh) public.

[image: screenshot of System Monitor]

Comment: The -n flag for git clean means dry run, so that command doesn't actually get anything done. You should find out why that is being run, perhaps "ps --forest -aA" can help you find what calls git.